# VBA Listbox displaying error symbol with currency formatting

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am using a ListBox in a UserForm to display the data from a Table in my worksheets. All the data is correctly formatted in the table but in the ListBox, the currency is being displayed with an "error symbol" which should simply be a space (as per the french standard for currency formatting) and looks like the following :

[image: Incorrect formatting]

I won't add the code for the UserForm since I am only having issues when inserting the data into the ListBox. However, below is the code responsible for populating said ListBox where `msOperationTable` is of type `ListObject` :

```
TableEntries.ColumnCount = 6
TableEntries.ColumnHeads = True
TableEntries.ColumnWidths = "100; 140; 150; 85; 100; 70"
TableEntries.RowSource = msOperationTable.Parent.Name & "!" & msOperationTable.DataBodyRange.Address
```

I haven't been able to find any explanation as to why this happens and I am starting to wonder if there is anything that can be done to fix this.

Comment: But what character is replaced by the question mark? The dot, used as thousands separator? What thousands separator should be according to your localization?

Comment: I'll add this information in the question but the seperator is simply a space

Comment: How to be a space? Shouldn't it be numeric? I cannot get you... Do you mean something like `1 0000,00 €`?

Comment: Exactly, the weird question mark symbol should be a space and the display should be `1 000,00 €` instead of `1?000,00 €`

Comment: Can you show us what kind of format did you apply, since it should look as you say? Excel is trying to guess the format (to be numeric if ending in €), but it looks it cannot do it... Did you set this weird format on purpose, or it is something coming from a different source?

Comment: The format applied in the cells (on a worksheet) is the basic accounting format: 2 decimal places and the € symbol. In the ListBox, as you can see I am simply applying the RowSource property where the last column is formatted with the accounting format stated before

Comment: Then, how to space between `1` and `000,00 €` did appear?